# topological properties of $G_{\delta}$ sets in a compact Hausdorff space

Tags: lo.logic, gn.general-topology

I am trying to understand a family of types $\mathcal{F}$ in the set $S(A)$,the set of complete types over $A$ (in the sense of [types in model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_(model_theory))) which is a compact and Haurdorff space equipped with the logic topology.  The family $\mathcal{F}$  turns out to be a $G_{\delta}$ set. Hence the following questions came up:

1. What is know about the subspace topology induced over a $G_{\delta}$ set?
2. Is there any possible topology that one could induce over $S(A)$ that makes and $F_{\sigma}$ set closed?
3. Which properties of convergence could be stated among sequences in a $G_{\delta}$ set?

Any comment, help or reference will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The notation $S(A)$ could mean anything. If you don't explain your notation no one will be able to answer.

Comment: thanks, I just edited the question

Comment: Good, thank you. It could also help in parts 1 and 3 if you gave some idea of what you're looking for, or an example of the kind of answer you would want ... otherwise these questions are too open-ended.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know precisely what I am looking for. More precisely, I know that $S^{*}(A) \backslash \mathcal{F}$ can be expressed as a union of sets $C_{\phi}$ where $C_{\phi}$ is the intersection of open sets. I am trying to characterize the set of types $\mathcal{F}$ in a different way, so it will be useful to know if there is some level of weak compactness that one could use. Or which topological properties does the $G_{\delta}$ set ($\mathcal{F}$) preserves from the old space.

Comment: "Types" as in type theory, or "types" as in homotopy theory, or "types" as in a programming language? The word "type" has many meanings, I think you should explain your terminology or provide a reference. What is a "type over $A$"?

Comment: @AndrejBauer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_(model_theory)

Comment: Thanks, @EmilJeřábek. I retracted my close vote.

Comment: Ok, my apologies for the ambiguity. I meant first order types, i.e. complete consistent sets of formulas over some set of parameters $A$ in some model $M$ of a first order theory $T$.

Comment: I don’t know what topological properties you are interested in, but as a trivial observation, since $S(A)$ is compact Hausdorff, its $G_\delta$ subspaces are Baire spaces. If moreover $S(A)$ is second-countable (i.e., when $A$ and the underlying first-order language are countable), then its $G_\delta$ subspaces are completely metrizable (i.e., Polish spaces).

Comment: Also, the description in the comment doesn’t work out. Assuming you mean *countable* intersections and unions (otherwise it doesn’t make sense at all), if the complement of $\mathcal F$ is a countable union of countable intersections of open sets, that only makes $\mathcal F$ an $F_{\sigma\delta}$ set (i.e, $\Pi_3$ in the Borel hierarchy), not $G_\delta$.

Comment: Maybe I should also state the obvious: all subspaces of $S(A)$ are Hausdorff and zero-dimensional (hence $T_{3\frac12}$).

Comment: If it helps at all (e.g. to find literature), $G_\delta$ subsets of compact Hausdorff spaces are sometimes called *Čech-complete* spaces. Also, these spaces are characterized by having a complete sequence of open covers (i.e a sequence $\{\mathcal{U}_n\}_{n \in \omega}$ of open covers of the space such that any filter on the space that intersects them all has an accumulation point).

Comment: Thanks Ramiro! Yes, that reference was very useful!